# Async fetch a function into another node.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to fetch events from Google Calendar. I have code to do that in a js file (googlecal.js) I have posted the function that lists the events. Now I want to write a new js file and get the list of these events from the googlecal.js file.
Fairly new to JS, would appreciate a direction for this.

```
function listEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const eve = res.data.items;
    if (eve.length) {
      //console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      eve.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        //console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);

        var attendee = event.attendees;

      });
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```

I tried to use module.exports or exporting this function and importing in a new file. But I am not very sure how to export it and import in the other js file, which is where I am facing the problem.

Comment: You should look for a nodejs tutorial, which explains module.exports, async calls and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can export this function as the top level/default through `module.exports = listEvents` if this is all you're interested in exporting, and use it as `const listEvents = require('./googlecal')` (the path would mean that the importer is at the same level).

Another popular convention is to export as an object so you have space to expand your module's exported funtionalities:

```
module.exports = { 
  listEvents,
  // future stuff
}
```

And use it so by leveraging destructuring: `const { listEvents } = require('./googlecal')`

Comment: I did that. But I can't fetch the variable 'attendee' from the other js file. It gives me undefines

Comment: @DeepenPanchal that’s a different problem. The function itself should `return` something, probably the fetched object from google calendars. That is not just a js thing.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment support ES6 Module syntax, you can use `import` and `export`, if not then you should use `require` and `module.exports`.

if you are going to use `module.exports` then just add `module.exports = { listEvents }` and importing it with `const { listEvents } = require('./path/to/your/file')`

You can read this for using `export`:

[How to use import/export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)